# Push footer to bottom of page (bootstrap)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a site I'm building, and I'm stuck. The site uses bootstrap, and I'm having problems getting the footer to stay at the bottom of the page regardless of whether there is content or not. *I don't want it to stay in the viewport, I want it to be at the end of the content.* This is the tutorial I'm following, but it's not working: http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/keeping-footers-at-the-bottom-of-the-page

**Right now the footer is stuck in the middle of the content.**

I have a theory that the `#container` id is not covering all the `#body` content. When I inspect the elements, it looks like the `#container` stops after the `<div class = "jumbotron home"></div>` and `<h1>oot</h1>` elements. I'm not sure why this is, or even if I'm right.

You can see it here: https://oot-janaaron97.c9users.io

Here's the code:

**style.css**

```
/*

Theme Name: Oot
Author: Deep Space Development Team 
Version: 1.0

*/

/******************************************************************************************

GENERIC STYLES

******************************************************************************************/

body{
    background: #fdfdfd;
}

a{
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.jumbotron{
    margin: 0 !important;
}




/******************************************************************************************

HEADER

******************************************************************************************/

.navbar-default{

}

.navbar-nav{
    float: right !important;

}

.navbar-brand{
    color: #333 !important;
}

#logo{
    width: auto;
    height: 30px;
    margin-top: -5px;
}


/******************************************************************************************

FOOTER

******************************************************************************************/

#footer{
    background: deepskyblue;
}

#footer p, #footer a{
    margin-top: 1.6em;
    color: #fff;
}



/******************************************************************************************

HOME

******************************************************************************************/

.home{
    background:linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)), url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1457213453084-d386450c6252?crop=entropy&dpr=2&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=700&ixjsv=2.1.0&ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=50&w=1300);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    height: 40em;


}


/******************************************************************************************
MISC.
******************************************************************************************/

.center{
    text-align: center;
}

.text-wrap{
    word-wrap: break-word;
}



/******************************************************************************************************

CODE TO KEEP FOOTER ON BOTTOM

******************************************************************************************************/
html,
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:100%;
}
#container {
    min-height:100%;
    position:relative;
}
#header {
    background:#ededed;
    padding:10px;
}
#body {
    padding-bottom:100px; /* Height of the footer element */
}
#footer {
    background:#ffab62;
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
}

/******************************************************************************************

MEDIA-QUERY

******************************************************************************************/

@media (max-width: 768px) {

    .nav li a{
        margin-left: 15px;
    }

    .navbar-nav{
        float: none !important;

    }

    .navbar-nav li{
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
    }



}
```

**header.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


        <!-- Bootstrap-->
        <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

        <!-- Custom css file -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/style.css" />

        <title>Oot</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id = "container">

            <div id = "header">
                <?php include 'menu.php'; ?>
            </div><!--end of #header-->

            <div id = "body">
```

**page-home.php**

```
<?php get_header();?>


                <div class = "jumbotron home"></div>

                <h1 class = "center text-wrap">Oot</h1>


                <div class = "col-md-4">
                    <p class = "text-wrap">fkdjfkdsfjdsfja;dfjdskjafkdsjfkdsjfkdsljfkldsfdsfdsffkdjfkdsfjdsfja;dfjdskjafkdsjfkdsjfkdsljfkldsfdsfdsffkdjfkdsfjdsfja;dfjdskjafkdsjfkdsjfkdsljfkldsfdsfdsffkdjfkdsfjdsfja;dfjdskjafkdsjfkdsjfkdsljfkldsfdsfdsffkdjfkdsfjdsfja;dfjdskjafkdsjfkdsjfkdsljfkldsfdsfdsffkdjfkdsfjdsfja;dfjdskjafkdsjfkdsjfkdsljfkldsfdsfdsffkdjfkdsfjdsfja;dfjdskjafkdsjfkdsjfkdsljfkldsfdsfdsffkdjfkdsfjdsfja;dfjdskjafkdsjfkdsjfkdsljfkldsfdsfdsf</p><p class = "text-wrap">fkdjfkdsfjdsfja;dfjdskjafkdsjfkdsjfkdsljfkldsfdsfdsffkdjfkdsfjdsfja;dfjdskjafkdsjfkdsjfkdsljfkldsfdsfdsffkdjfkdsfjdsfja;dfjdskjafkdsjfkdsjfkdsljfkldsfdsfdsffkdjfkdsfjdsfja;dfjdskjafkdsjfkdsjfkdsljfkldsfdsfdsffkdjfkdsfjdsfja;dfjdskjafkdsjfkdsjfkdsljfkldsfdsfdsffkdjfkdsfjdsfja;dfjdskjafkdsjfkdsjfkdsljfkldsfdsfdsffkdjfkdsfjdsfja;dfjdskjafkdsjfkdsjfkdsljfkldsfdsfdsffkdjfkdsfjdsfja;dfjdskjafkdsjfkdsjfkdsljfkldsfdsfdsf</p>
                </div>

                <div class = "col-md-4">
                    <p class = "text-wrap">fkdjfkdsfjdsfja;dfjdskjafkdsjfkdsjfkdsljfkldsfdsfdsffkdjfkdsfjdsfja;dfjdskjafkdsjfkdsjfkdsljfkldsfdsfdsffkdjfkdsfjdsfja;dfjdskjafkdsjfkdsjfkdsljfkldsfdsfdsffkdjfkdsfjdsfja;dfjdskjafkdsjfkdsjfkdsljfkldsfdsfdsffkdjfkdsfjdsfja;dfjdskjafkdsjfkdsjfkdsljfkldsfdsfdsffkdjfkdsfjdsfja;dfjdskjafkdsjfkdsjfkdsljfkldsfdsfdsffkdjfkdsfjdsfja;dfjdskjafkdsjfkdsjfkdsljfkldsfdsfdsffkdjfkdsfjdsfja;dfjdskjafkdsjfkdsjfkdsljfkldsfdsfdsf</p><p class = "text-wrap">fkdjfkdsfjdsfja;dfjdskjafkdsjfkdsjfkdsljfkldsfdsfdsffkdjfkdsfjdsfja;dfjdskjafkdsjfkdsjfkdsljfkldsfdsfdsffkdjfkdsfjdsfja;dfjdskjafkdsjfkdsjfkdsljfkldsfdsfdsffkdjfkdsfjdsfja;dfjdskjafkdsjfkdsjfkdsljfkldsfdsfdsffkdjfkdsfjdsfja;dfjdskjafkdsjfkdsjfkdsljfkldsfdsfdsffkdjfkdsfjdsfja;dfjdskjafkdsjfkdsjfkdsljfkldsfdsfdsffkdjfkdsfjdsfja;dfjdskjafkdsjfkdsjfkdsljfkldsfdsfdsffkdjfkdsfjdsfja;dfjdskjafkdsjfkdsjfkdsljfkldsfdsfdsf</p>
                </div>

                <div class = "col-md-4">
                    <p class = "text-wrap">fkdjfkdsfjdsfja;dfjdskjafkdsjfkdsjfkdsljfkldsfdsfdsffkdjfkdsfjdsfja;dfjdskjafkdsjfkdsjfkdsljfkldsfdsfdsffkdjfkdsfjdsfja;dfjdskjafkdsjfkdsjfkdsljfkldsfdsfdsffkdjfkdsfjdsfja;dfjdskjafkdsjfkdsjfkdsljfkldsfdsfdsffkdjfkdsfjdsfja;dfjdskjafkdsjfkdsjfkdsljfkldsfdsfdsffkdjfkdsfjdsfja;dfjdskjafkdsjfkdsjfkdsljfkldsfdsfdsffkdjfkdsfjdsfja;dfjdskjafkdsjfkdsjfkdsljfkldsfdsfdsffkdjfkdsfjdsfja;dfjdskjafkdsjfkdsjfkdsljfkldsfdsfdsf</p><p class = "text-wrap">fkdjfkdsfjdsfja;dfjdskjafkdsjfkdsjfkdsljfkldsfdsfdsffkdjfkdsfjdsfja;dfjdskjafkdsjfkdsjfkdsljfkldsfdsfdsffkdjfkdsfjdsfja;dfjdskjafkdsjfkdsjfkdsljfkldsfdsfdsffkdjfkdsfjdsfja;dfjdskjafkdsjfkdsjfkdsljfkldsfdsfdsffkdjfkdsfjdsfja;dfjdskjafkdsjfkdsjfkdsljfkldsfdsfdsffkdjfkdsfjdsfja;dfjdskjafkdsjfkdsjfkdsljfkldsfdsfdsffkdjfkdsfjdsfja;dfjdskjafkdsjfkdsjfkdsljfkldsfdsfdsffkdjfkdsfjdsfja;dfjdskjafkdsjfkdsjfkdsljfkldsfdsfdsf</p>
                </div>


            </div>


<?php get_footer();?>
```

**footer.php**

```
            <div id = "footer">

                    <div class = "col-md-4">
                        <h1>TEST</h1>
                        <p>heloo wookfodfkdf;askfdsafasfasdfdsafsf</p>
                    </div>

                    <div class = "col-md-4">
                        <h1>TEST</h1>
                        <p>heloo wookfodfkdf;askfdsafasfasdfdsafsf</p>
                    </div>

                    <div class = "col-md-4">
                        <h1>TEST</h1>
                        <p>heloo wookfodfkdf;askfdsafasfasdfdsafsf</p>
                    </div>


            </div>

        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks!

Comment: You're looking for a "sticky footer", I believe.

Comment: Can you create a demo with the generated HTML markup rather than php..?

Comment: plnkr for anyone interested in trying to solve this - https://plnkr.co/edit/rhDZV4jNUiHkkVg0yOOW?p=preview

Comment: The php loads the header.php and the footer.php files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your #footer css to the following:

```
#footer {
    background: #ffab62;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    /* position: absolute; - remove this*/
    /* bottom: 0; - remove this*/
    /* left: 0; - remove this*/
}
```

The footer will then just naturally sit wherever your `<body>` content ends

===

**UPDATED ANSWER**

Try adding the class of clearfix to the body

```
<div id="body" class="clearfix">
```

Comment: no, that didn't quite do it. the footer is gone, and the `.col-md-4`s aren't aligned. They are at the end of the content, but if the content isn't the same, the `.col-md-4`s will not be aligned, because they follow the content.

Comment: like if some of the content is longer than the other, the `.col-md-4`s will not be aligned.

Comment: Have you got a [fiddle link](https://fiddle.jshell.net/) to the code that you could post?

Comment: though at least on my computer that jsFiddle's preview is showing the mobile version, so the footer is at the bottom. On desktop the footer is still not right.

Comment: here's a better way to see what I'm talking about: https://oot-janaaron97.c9users.io

Comment: Great thanks - think its a clearfix issue. I've updated my original answer

Comment: THAT DID IT! THANKS!